# There were 2 different questions related to same problem, I provided same answer for both the questions, moderator deleted one

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, duplicate-answers

There were 2 different questions related to same problem, I provided same answer for both the questions, moderator deleted one. I was just trying to help if someone stumbled upon the similar error.
I don't know why it was such a big deal that moderator went ahead and deleted it.
I am sure deleting it will not help anybody. 
Please provide a capability to add a comment in deleted answer so that we can explain to moderator why a duplicate answer was added.

Comment: This is so funny, people are down voting a question asked for clarification on a deleted question. Keep down voting folks.

Comment: Check [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/863618/answered-both-orig-and-dupe) SEDE query, but read also my extended answer.

Answer (score 17):

If two questions show the same problem, and are similar enough, you should be answering one, and voting or flagging the other one to close it as a duplicate.

If they're *very* similar but different, showing awareness of how they are different is a good idea. I'd recommend maybe including a link to the other answer, with  "similar to my answer here" and tailoring your answers to the specific issues - with something like "however, you may find that you need to polarise the retro encombulator in this case". If you're posting carbon-copy answers, you're doing it wrong.

We often have to deal with folks figuring it's easy rep and posting 4-5 identical answers in a short span to questions that ought to be closed as duplicates.

If you need to get in touch with a moderator over a decision you can, IIRC, flag your own posts for moderator attention. I don't think that without an edit, it would do much good though.

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the questions should have been closed as dupe, typically it happens. You didn't write link, so we can't check it.

Posting the same answer twice in this case is generally not nice.

In the rare case that multiple, essentially different questions have the same answer, I think it is ok.

Mod power misuses are not very common, typically as a commoner you will unlikely that you face some of them. Even if they happen, they happen on much better hidden ways.

<sub>Extension: This [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/863618/answered-both-orig-and-dupe) shows all the cases as somebody answered both the original question and its dupe. There are 11567 such cases on the Stack Overflow (about 15million questions). It seems the practice is more common as it should be, however it also means that the mods are typically more lenient about the practice as in your case happened. (Furthermore, the dupe closure is a collective decision which may be different as the view of the answerers. Furthermore, the answerers should not be obligated to remember all their previous answers. Thus, the overwhelming majority of such cases is obviously good-standing from all the sides.) But they should not be, and it is their decision. Don't worry on that - other time you will have more luck.</sub>

Comment: whoops....@peterh, you really spent some time building this query to make me feel better :), thanks for your help.

Comment: @NirmalMangal Thanks :-) Writing SEDE queries is my hobby :-) It wasn't so hard, [I have a lot](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/13374/peterh?order_by=favorite), I just refactored it from some of my previous ones.